# how to find out or fetch all friend list of facebook with their profile pic,name and id

Tags: android, facebook

I am working in one application in which I have to fetch all the friends list from Facebook.

I have implemented code like this :

```
Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook("141118172662401");
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "name,id");
mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", params, "GET", new FriendListRequestListener(), null);
    }
});
}

public class FriendListRequestListener {
  public void onComplete(final String response) {
      _error = null;
        try {
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final JSONArray friends = json.getJSONArray("data");
            FacebookFriendsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                JSONObject data;
                public void run() {
                try{

                    try {
                        data = Util.parseJson(response);
                    } catch (FacebookError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JSONArray friendsData = data.getJSONArray("data");
                   // mDbAdapter.deleteAllFriends();

                    for (int i = 0; i < friendsData.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject friend = friendsData.getJSONObject(i);
                       /* mDbAdapter.addFriend(friend.getString("name"),
                                friend.getString("id"));*/
                    }
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            _error = "JSON Error in response";
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            _error = "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }

        if (_error != null)
        {
            FacebookFriendsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred:  " + 
                                    _error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Throws Error in this line :

> mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", params, "GET", new FriendListRequestListener(), null);

What is wrong in this? also added Asyncronous class..

If there are any other methods or sources to find out Facebook friends then please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this for getting 
Friend List.

```
    public class FriendsList extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener 
{

    private Handler mHandler;
    protected ListView friendsList;
    protected static JSONArray jsonArray;
    protected String graph_or_fql;

    /*
     * Layout the friends' list
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mHandler = new Handler();
        setContentView(R.layout.friends_list);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String apiResponse = extras.getString("API_RESPONSE");
        graph_or_fql = extras.getString("METHOD");
        try {
            if(graph_or_fql.equals("graph")) {
                jsonArray = new JSONObject(apiResponse).getJSONArray("data");
            } else {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(apiResponse);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        friendsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
        friendsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        friendsList.setAdapter(new FriendListAdapter(this));

        showToast(getString(R.string.can_post_on_wall));
    }

    /*
     * Clicking on a friend should popup a dialog for user to post on friend's wall.
     */

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        try {   
            final long friendId;
            if(graph_or_fql.equals("graph")) {
                friendId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getLong("id");
            } else {
                friendId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getLong("uid");
            }
            String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("name");


            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.post_on_wall_title)
            .setMessage(String.format(getString(R.string.post_on_wall), name))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                    /*
                     * Source Tag: friend_wall_tag
                     * To write on a friend's wall, provide friend's UID in the 'to' parameter.
                     * More info on feed dialog - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
                     */
                    params.putString("to", String.valueOf(friendId));
                    params.putString("caption", getString(R.string.app_name));
                    params.putString("description", getString(R.string.app_desc));
                    params.putString("picture", Utility.HACK_ICON_URL);
                    params.putString("name", getString(R.string.app_action));
                    Utility.mFacebook.dialog(FriendsList.this, "feed", params, new PostDialogListener());
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
            .show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /*
     * Callback after the message has been posted on friend's wall.
     */
    public class PostDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");     
            if (postId != null) {                                                                                   
                showToast("Message posted on the wall.");            
            } else {                                                                                                
                showToast("No message posted on the wall.");                                                                       
            }   
        }
    }

    public void showToast(final String msg) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(FriendsList.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Definition of the list adapter
     */
    public class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        FriendsList friendsList;

        public FriendListAdapter(FriendsList friendsList) {
            this.friendsList = friendsList;
            if(Utility.model == null) {
                Utility.model = new FriendsGetProfilePics();
            }
            Utility.model.setListener(this);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(friendsList.getBaseContext());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return jsonArray.length();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            View hView = convertView;
            if(convertView == null) {
                hView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_item, null);
                ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.profile_pic = (ImageView)hView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
                holder.name = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.info = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.info);
                hView.setTag(holder);
            }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();
            try {
                if(graph_or_fql.equals("graph")) {
                    holder.profile_pic.setImageBitmap(Utility.model.getImage(jsonObject.getString("id"), jsonObject.getString("picture")));
                } else {
                    holder.profile_pic.setImageBitmap(Utility.model.getImage(jsonObject.getString("uid"), jsonObject.getString("pic_square")));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                holder.name.setText("");
            }
            try {
                holder.name.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                holder.name.setText("");
            }
            try {
                if(graph_or_fql.equals("graph")) {
                    holder.info.setText(jsonObject.getJSONObject("location").getString("name"));
                } else {
                    JSONObject location = jsonObject.getJSONObject("current_location");
                    holder.info.setText(location.getString("city") + ", " + location.getString("state"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                holder.info.setText("");
            }
            return hView;
        }   

    }


    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView profile_pic;
        TextView name;
        TextView info;
    }
}
```

And for FriendsGetProfilePics

```
   public class FriendsGetProfilePics
{


    Hashtable<String, Bitmap> friendsImages;
    Hashtable<String, String> positionRequested;
    BaseAdapter listener;
    int runningCount = 0;
    Stack<ItemPair> queue;

    /*
     * 15 max async tasks at any given time.
     */
    final int MAX_ALLOWED_TASKS = 15;

    public FriendsGetProfilePics() {
        friendsImages = new Hashtable<String, Bitmap>();
        positionRequested = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        queue = new Stack<ItemPair>();
    }

    /*
     * Inform the listener when the image has been downloaded. 
     * listener is FriendsList here.
     */
    public void setListener(BaseAdapter listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        reset();
    }

    public void reset() {
        positionRequested.clear();
        runningCount = 0;
        queue.clear();
    }

    /*
     * If the profile pictore has already been downloaded and cached, return it
     * else excecute a new async task to fetch it - 
     * if total async tasks >15, queue the request.
     */
    public Bitmap getImage(String uid, String url) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)friendsImages.get(uid);
        if(image != null) {
            return image;
        }
        if(!positionRequested.containsKey(uid)) {
            positionRequested.put(uid, "");
            if (runningCount >= MAX_ALLOWED_TASKS) {
                queue.push(new ItemPair(uid, url));
            } else {
                runningCount++;
                new GetProfilePicAsyncTask().execute(uid, url);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void getNextImage() {
        if(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            ItemPair item = (ItemPair)queue.pop();
            new GetProfilePicAsyncTask().execute(item.uid, item.url);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Start a AsyncTask to fetch the request
     */
    private class GetProfilePicAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {
         String uid;
         protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
             this.uid = (String)params[0];
             String url = (String)params[1];
             return Utility.getBitmap(url);
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
             runningCount--;
             if(result != null) {
                 friendsImages.put(uid, result);
                 listener.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 getNextImage();
             }
         }
    }

    class ItemPair {
        String uid;
        String url;

        public ItemPair(String uid, String url) {
            this.uid = uid;
            this.url = url;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is there any query then please feel free to ask..!

Comment: hi..mehul..i m not understanding that Utility class..n also,from where m i getting that "API_RESPONSE" and "METHOD"..
can u please elobrate more...

Comment: Hi..@Kutbi Please download this and use Hackbook example

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/downloads

Comment: thanks a lot .. friend..coz of u i am able to get friends list..
in my app i have to do one thing more...that is : i have to send message as a chat to the selected friends of fb .. do u have any idea regarding this...???

Comment: Hi..Mehul i ask question related to Facebook messenger in S.O.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500719/how-to-make-facebook-messenger-like-application-in-my-android-application

Comment: I get login from one activity and then I want to get friend list from other activity then how to perform the task without next time login,,