# How to fetch a profile picture from facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am writing an android app, in which I want to fetch a list of all my facebook-friends along with their names and profile pictures.

In my sample code I am getting the name of my friends but not the profile picture, please tell me the reason why i am facing this problem:

```
       @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_tab, parent, false);
    }

    if (position >= myFriends.size()) {
        return v;
    }

    MyFriend friend = myFriends.get(position);
    ImageView icon_pic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_pic);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(friend.getPic());
        InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
        Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "fb");
        icon_pic.setImageDrawable(image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "myadapter: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

MyFacebook.java

```
 public void init(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
    mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    isReady = false;
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    mFacebook.authorize(main, new String[] { "publish_stream",
            "friends_birthday", "friends_photos"  }, new MyAuthorizeListener());
}

// ref- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/
public Report reLoadAllFriends() {
    if (!isReady) {
        Log.v(TAG, "myfacebook.reloadallfriends Not ready yet!");
        return new Report(false, "Not ready yet!");
    }

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "id,name,birthday,picture");
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", params, new MyRequestListener(
            RequestType.FRIEND_LIST));

    Log.v(TAG, "myfacebook.reloadallfriends Fetch started.");
    return new Report(true, "Fetch started");
}

public List<MyFriend> getAllFriends() {
    return getFilteredFriends(null);
}

public List<MyFriend> getFilteredFriends(com.january.floogoo.Filter week) {
    return Main.db.getFriendsFilteredBy(week);
}

public List<Map<String, String>> getAllFriendsAsMap() {
    return getFilteredFriendsAsMap(null);
}

public List<Map<String, String>> getFilteredFriendsAsMap(Filter filterBy) {
    List<MyFriend> friendList = Main.db.getFriendsFilteredBy(filterBy);

    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (MyFriend friend : friendList) {
        list.add(friend.getMap());
    }
    return list;
}

public void post(String receiver, String message) {
    if (isReady) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", message);

        mAsyncRunner.request(receiver + "/feed", params, "POST",
                new MyRequestListener(RequestType.FEED_POST));
    }
}

class MyAuthorizeListener extends BaseDialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Authorization successfull");
        isReady = true;
        main.loadContents();
    }
}

class MyRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
    private RequestType type;

    public MyRequestListener(RequestType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void onComplete(final String response) {
        try {
            switch (type) {
            case FRIEND_LIST:
                 Log.d(TAG, "myfacebook.friendlist Response: "
                 + response.toString());
                myFriends.clear();
                JSONArray jarr = Util.parseJson(response).getJSONArray(
                        "data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String fbID = json.getString("id");
                    String name = json.getString("name");
                    String bday = json.optString("birthday");
                    String pic = json.getString("picture");

                    myFriends.add(new MyFriend(fbID, name, bday, pic));
                }
                main.notifyMain(Note.FRIENDLIST_RELOADED); 
                break;
            case FEED_POST:
                Log.d(TAG, "myfacebook.feedpost Response: "
                        + response.toString());
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

==================================================================

```
    ImageView icon_pic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_pic);
     try{
     URL img_value = null;
     String id = null;
 img_value = new URL
      ("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");            
       Bitmap mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream
        (img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
     icon_pic.setImageBitmap(mIcon);
     }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "myadapter: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

======================================================================

Original Code is here:

https://github.com/prajwol/Birthday-Reminder

I have two packages in my app, first - *com.january.floogoo* [my custom classes package]

and second - *com.facebook.android* [classes related to facebook SDK]

I am using 10 classes in **com.facebook.android** package, namely:

1. *AsyncFacebookRunner.java*
2. *BaseDialogListener.java*
3. *BaseRequestListener.java*
4. *DialogError.java*
5. *Facebook.java*
6. *FacebookError.java*
7. *FbDialog.java*
8. *SessionEvents.java*
9. *SessionStore.java*
10. *Util.java*

Here my question is Am i missing something ? If yes so please help me...

Comment: Which problem you face in this code?Do you try with my code below to view profile pics?Show logcat views here if those code results error.

Comment: first of all tell, what's the problem with this code, secondly post the logcat if there is any error.

Comment: @Liza the problem is you are calling any other network thread on main thread so it shows..
have you using AsyncTask...???

Comment: Do you create your application id from facebook first which you use in APP_ID?

Comment: @ridoy yes i have created and i am using that one in my application and able to fetch name and dob for my all fb friends, and by this kind of your efforts i have no words to say Thank, still i am trying your code...

Comment: @ridoy i have used your code see above not getting any error but unable to get an image

Comment: See it..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454882/how-to-find-out-or-fetch-all-friend-list-of-facebook-with-their-profile-pic-name

Comment: @ridoy ya.. that is from hackbook sample code, i am strongly believe on you if i will send you my complete code so could you please do these small changes for me in my existing code.. I can't use Hackbook sample because i have to make my app more custom

Comment: I have an app(Facebook Birthday Reminder) in Google Play Store,so some days ago we(i along with 2 friends) work on it.But during coding we ignore profile picture option,because if you have 500 friends then it will take long time to load all of those pics which is time consuming for an user.Yes,i may help you in this topic.But tomorrow is my exam,so if you are in a hurry i can't help you,Best wishes to you..:)

Comment: @ridoy I have to submit this project within next 2days, if possible so please send me that sample app to get Facebook Birthday Reminders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below link to fetch the profile pictures from facebook.

https://github.com/chrtatu/FacebookFriendsList  after logging in you will be getting list of friends pictures.

FriendsList.Java is the class where your facebook friends get sync.

Comment: if i also want to fetch dob and name of friends then what source code i have to use or any link like you have shown last one...

Comment: from above one you will get friends list as well as profile pictures, same as these things you have to add the birthday permission to get the data of birth..

Comment: that you need to sort in your list view according to the date of birth...(Date sorting in java )

Comment: see the below link http://code.google.com/p/date-sorting-example/source/browse/trunk/date-util-test/src/date/util/test/DateUtil.java?r=3

Comment: see this link also http://www.coderanch.com/t/409273/java/java/date-sorting-program

Comment: thanks a lot.. still i am getting list of friends alphabetically if i want to get that in order of upcoming bdays so what i need to write

Comment: please don't mind i am new in android, i have seen date sorting sample now i want to use this functionality in my code to get list of friends in order of upcoming birthdays, how to use that code in existing one https://github.com/chrtatu/FacebookFriendsList

Answer (score 2):

Try with..

```
 ImageView icon_pic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_pic);
 URL img_value = null;
 img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");
 Bitmap mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
 icon_pic.setImageBitmap(mIcon);
```

Where id is one of your friend profile ID.